# How do I sort a query object which is a StringListProperty()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting

I have this model:

```
class ArticleTagList(db.Model):
    article_tags = db.StringListProperty()
```

In the `EditArticleHandler` I do:

```
        tag_query = ArticleTagList.all()

        for tag in tag_query:
            for i in range(len(tag.article_tags)):

                self.response.out.write(""" <span id="small-tags">
                <input type="checkbox" name="article_tag" value="%s">%s  </span>"""
                 % (tag.article_tags[i], tag.article_tags[i]))
```

But it would be nice to print these tags in alpabetical order.

Of course trying

```
        tag_query.sort()
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

How do I sort the queried list? Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks for the answers. I am having difficulty understanding query results so not sure I understand the comments below; but this is how I solved it and I would appreciate comments why this a good solution or why it is not a good solution. (for instance, is it still wrong to use `range()` to iterate?) Thanks!

```
    query = ArticleTagList.all()
    items = query.get()

    items.article_tags.sort()

    for i in range(len(items.article_tags)):
        self.response.out.write(""" <span id="small-tags">
            <input type="checkbox" name="article_tag" value="%s">%s  </span>"""
             % (items.article_tags[i], items.article_tags[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to print the tags in order, but you're attempting to sort the instances, instead. You should be doing something like this:

```
for taglist in tag_query:
  for tag in sorted(taglist.article_tags):
    #...
```

But given that you probably always want them in sorted order, it'd be easier to call `taglist.article_tags.sort()` on the entity when you create it, and before you store it, to ensure the tags are stored in sorted order.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand what I am doing wrong. In the model `ArticleTagList` I have the property `article_tags` which is a list. I want to query this list and sort it before I display it. How do I do this? And I understand that it is better to save the list as a sorted list, as you say. How do I save it as a sorted list? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel: To display it sorted, use the first code snippet in my answer. To sort it before you store it, use the second code snippet when you first create the entity, and before you call `.put()` on it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
    for article_tag_list in tag_query:
        article_tags = sorted(article_tag_list.article_tags)
        for tag in article_tags:
            self.response.out.write("""<span id="small-tags">
            <input type="checkbox" name="article_tag" value="%s">%s  </span>"""
             % (tag, tag))
```

Comment: `tag_query` returns `ArticleTagList` instances, not lists of tags.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: I am still confused about what queries return. I was getting "query object does not have sort method" or something like this. What is the good way of thinking about query results? Since this is a `StringListProperty` it is confusing that what is returned is not a list. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel Query objects are, well, objects. If you iterate over them using a for loop, they return Entities - in this case, `ArticleTagList` instances. If you call `.fetch(num)` on them (which is more efficient), they return a list of entities.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't iterate through a list by doing `for i in range(len(tag.article_tags))`. There's no reason for it. `for tag in tag.article_tags` works much better and is more Pythonic.

To answer your question though, don't forget you have two list-like things here: the set of `ArticleTagList` instances, and the list of `article_tags` within each instance. Are you trying to sort all the tags, no matter which taglist they are in? In which case, you will need to join them all into one big list:

```
full_list = []
for tag in tag_query:
    full_list.extend(list(tag.article_tags))

full_list.sort()
```

Comment: "the set of ArticleTagList instances, and the list of article_tags within each instance." I don't understand what this means or which of my variables refer to which. I would appreciate more explanation on this. Thanks.